# check if my Snowflake database connection is established

Tags: spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, spring-jdbc

I want to check if my Snowflake database connection is established or not in a spring boot application using a simple query. I have given the details of DB in the application.properties file. Can someone suggest to me how can I do that?I tried using jdbcTemplate.query  but it becomes too complex.

Comment: "Tried using" what?

Comment: jdbcTemplate.query

Comment: And why is that complex? You can simply do `SELECT 1`, for example